# I have created a layout for recycleView, when I am adding the image inside constraint layout, there is always a default margin in the top

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have created a layout for recycleView, when I am adding the image inside constraint layout, there is always a default margin in the top

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rv_bg">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/services"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I am attaching the screenshot of the layout, If anyone having the solution, please share

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlfdX.png)

Comment: Change gravity in ```LinearLayout```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the ConstraintLayout in LinearLayout?

Comment: Remove `android:paddingTop="10dp"` on the _ConstraintLayout__. It is looking like a margin on the _ImageView_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem, if you are too facing the problem, instead of ImageView, you can use this library called RoundedImageView

Github Link: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

1. Add the dependency to your app-level Gradle module
   implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
2. Sample XML file

---

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/services"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="10dp"
        app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="10dp"
        app:riv_mutate_background="false"
        app:riv_oval="false"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

This library helped me to solve my problem, do check out this once if you are also facing the same kind of issues.